# Do search engines consider GUID in indexing?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, multilingual, feeds

I've been reading the WordPress's codex recently, and noticed that WordPress is using a term called `GUID`. According to codex:

> The term "GUID" stands for "Globally Unique Identifier". It is a field
>   that is intended to hold an identifier for the post which a) is unique
>   across the whole of space and time and b) never, ever changes. The
>   GUID field is primarily used to create the WordPress feeds.

Let's assume we have a website with it's posts written in English. Now web decide to translate the website's posts to Russian, and publish it under another domain as it's sister website.

According to WordPress's codex, even after the translation, the translated posts will still have the same GUID as the original website.

The question is, will this affect indexing? Will google or other search engines/feed readers consider the translated posts as duplicate?

Comment: I am pretty sure SEs do not give a rip what WP does that others may not. Certainly, this does not seem like valuable data for search so I cannot imagine how it can help. Cheers!!

Comment: Where does it say that the GUID should be the same for translations? Or is this your assumption?

Comment: @unor It says in the WordPress codex, that never ever ever never ever change GUID under any circumstances.

Comment: @closetnoc thanks. WordPress itself seems very confident about their GUID system and it's importance.

Comment: @JackJohansson: Yes, never change it for an item. But a translation is a *new* item, so it gets its own, new GUID, no?

Comment: Yes that's what i thought. Since the translated articles are not considers the same articles anymore.

Comment: Why not check your own log server to see weather google request your rss feed or not. if they did not request often your rss feed, it means google don't care about your rss feed. They will simply rely on your sitemap links.

Comment: @Goyllo google hardly cares even about my sitemap (kappa). I just wanted to know if they officially rely on this or not.

Comment: That's why I said checkout your server logs, how someone can confirm, if they don't work at Google. We can just assume, and I assume they don't use it. To confirm, check your server side logs, and see Google ping your rss feed or not. If they don't ping it, it means they don't know anything inside it, including wp GUID as well.

Comment: Google officially supports hreflang, which is part of HTML and http standard for a while, and can be added to sitemap.xml as well. I think its a safe bet going that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to search engines duplicate content is not based on the GUID rather it is based on the content itself. How the search engine companies do this is a closely guarded proprietary secret but in very broad strokes is based on comparing the content of the page to other pages already in the index. Where page content is the same but in different languages then duplicate content penalties don't come into play as it is clearly demonstrated that the content is targeted at two different markets based on language.

As for the GUID aspect of the question search engines don't really consider the GUID of a wordpress article at all. The GUID is used in wordpress to uniquely identify the article across the internet, however search engines use the URL of the page in question to identify the page. If two pages have the same GUID search engines won't have any issue with it unless the content of the page is the same with the same language.

So based on your question given that the two sites which will have pages with the same GUID will be in different languages then you won't have any issues with search engines or feed readers.